Connecting ESP32 to Azure IoT Through GSM
I have been trying to connect my ESP32, which is connected to SIMCOM's SIM7600 GSM Module, to Azure IoT Service. Connecting to Azure IoT Service over WiFi was rather easy because there were already written example code. But for doing the same thing with GSM, I wasn't able to find much.
I tried few libraries and example codes but most of them are trying to make working WiFi code magically work with GSM module without doing much, as far as I understand.
Is there anything I'm missing here? Any sharing of a resource or an advice would be really appricated. I also can switch to IDF or any other way to program ESP32. I just need to establish GSM connection with Azure IoT.
Thanks for reading this far. And I'm sorry for not being able to share any code because I wasn't able to find much as a source.

I wasn't able to fund much. Have you try TinyGSM? Take a look at the httpsClient example in particular, once it is work, you can modified it for connecting to Azure IoT.

A GSM modem requires a basic dialup sequence and a PPP client to establish an Internet connection - once this is up and running you can use it as generic uplink. Espressif provides a component esp_modem which does that and supports the SIM7600. The best place to get started is the PPP over serial sample project. If you've connected the modem over USB instead of UART, pay attention to follow the relevant sample code. Note that this project works on ESP IDF, not Arduino.
Many modems also provide an alternative solution in the form on non-standard AT commands which allow the modem itself to create TCP/HTTP/etc connections. Those are rather painful to set up for anything except the most trivial use cases. They become useful in systems too small to run a TCP/IP stack, which doesn't include ESP32.
